# iOS Web App Inexplicable Opens YouTube App

Tags: ios, web

For the life of me, I can't figure out why my website's web app suddenly started automatically opening the YouTube app. Originally, I had a YouTube widget, which I removed thinking it might be the culprit, but no luck. Could anyone with more knowledge please shed some light on this?

Steps to re-create:

1. Add mtscollective.com to Home Screen via Safari
2. Load web app
3. "This video is unavailable" loads

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce your web app loads, though it is a bit slow even on wifi. No youtube problems.

Comment: @Drmorgan Hmm did the actual website load for you?

Comment: Yeah nav bar shows "more than sound collective", blog like feed with share buttons for fb/twitter/tumblur

Comment: @Drmorgan That's what I wanna see. Thanks for taking the time to test! Will have to continue testing internally

Comment: no problem! Try deleting all history and website data for safari in settings on the iPhone/iPad.  The youtube widget might be cached and is trying to load when safari opens and redirects too quickly before your page loads.  Also, I would recommend closing/deleting this question in the mean time. Sort of irrelevant to SO since it's not related to code-related issues.  Feel free to private message me if you need someone to check the website again as you test!